# Keep data frame size unchanged when subsetting values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to subset a data frame by dropping values but without dropping any columns.

**Example**

```
> df <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 1), c(4,5,6,7,3,0, 0)))
> df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  1
2  4  5  6  7  3  0  0
```

As expected, subsetting returns a smaller data frame:

```
> df[which(df[1,] > 2)]
  V3 V4 V5 V6
1  3  4  5  6
2  6  7  3  0
```

**How do I have subset return the below data frame?**

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6  V7
1  NA NA  3  4  5  6  NA
2  NA NA  6  7  3  0  NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't actually want to `subset` your data frame, you just want to blank out certain columns.  so just reverse the logic inside your `which` command..

```
df[ , df[ 1 , ] <= 2]

# and set all of _those_ values to NA
df[ , df[ 1 , ] <= 2] <- NA

# look at the result
df
```

note: if your data frame already contains `NA`s in the first column, the `<=` will return an `NA` which is probably not what you want.  just be sure whatever test you use doesn't return `NA` values.

Comment: And get rid of the which altogether since it's not doing anything here

Comment: @hadley maybe not here but what if the result of df[1,] <= 2 is NA?

Comment: @hadley ..i believe `which` is necessary here :D

Comment: `df[, df[1,] <= 2]` would be clearer.  @agstudy using which to remove `NA`s is not a very good idea - it's not clear, and introduces other possible bugs

Comment: @hadley with a fresh set of eyes, i see what you see.  updated w/ note :)